# ELIFECYCLE error with Webpack + React + Typescript

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin, webpack-config

quite new to bundling modules using Webpack but trying it out. I have a very simple project that I'm trying to bundle up to display it. Running a build script gives me the mysterious error:

```
$ npm run build

> react-extension-from-scratch@1.0.0 build /path/to/react-extension-from-scratch
> webpack --mode production

[webpack-cli] Compilation finished
assets by status 126 KiB [cached] 2 assets
orphan modules 196 bytes [orphan] 1 module
modules by path ./node_modules/ 133 KiB
  modules by path ./node_modules/react/ 6.48 KiB
    ./node_modules/react/index.js 190 bytes [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js 6.3 KiB [built] [code generated]
  modules by path ./node_modules/react-dom/ 119 KiB
    ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js 1.33 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.production.min.js 118 KiB [built] [code generated]
  modules by path ./node_modules/scheduler/ 4.91 KiB
    ./node_modules/scheduler/index.js 198 bytes [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.production.min.js 4.72 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./node_modules/object-assign/index.js 2.06 KiB [built] [code generated]
./src/index.tsx + 1 modules 453 bytes [built] [code generated]
1 ERROR in child compilations
webpack 5.11.0 compiled with 1 error in 2831 ms
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-extension-from-scratch@1.0.0 build: `webpack --mode production`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the react-extension-from-scratch@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /path/to/logfile.log
```

Below is my **Webpack** config:

```js
import path from 'path';
import webpack from 'webpack';
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

const config: webpack.Configuration = {
  context: __dirname,
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './src',
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  entry: {
    app: './src/index.tsx',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: ['html-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-typescript'],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'index.html'),
    }),
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [{ from: './src/manifest.json', to: '[name].[ext]' }],
    }),
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  stats: {
    errorDetails: true,
  },
};

export default config;
```

Curiously enough, the build works fine if I remove the `template` from the `HtmlWebpackPlugin`'s arguments (but obviously it doesn't then add the `index.html` file I want into the build directory).

For context, the idea is quite simple: In my src directory, I have an `index.html` file that has a div with an id that I inject some React code into. When building this, I'd like to bundle the `index.html` into the build directory and have it link to the generated `bundle.js` file so that the React code runs right away. I know I can use the `CopyWebpackPlugin` to achieve this but would have to manually include the `bundle.js` in it, which is fine for this toy project but would not want to do this for a more complicated project.

Anyone got ideas?